# 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused for twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have used belove code for a post on twitter

```
public class TwitterSocialHelper extends SocialHelper {

    private static final String TAG = TwitterSocialHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "AZZZZZ";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

    private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://abc";
    private static final String IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";

    private static final int AUTH_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private final Twitter twitter;
    private RequestToken requestToken;

    public TwitterSocialHelper(Activity activity, Listener listener) {
        super(TYPE_TWITTER, activity, listener);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        if (isConnected()) {
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(PreferencesManager.getTwitterToken(activity), PreferencesManager.getTwitterSecret(activity)));
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnected() {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(PreferencesManager.getTwitterToken(activity))
                && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PreferencesManager.getTwitterSecret(activity));
    }

    private void connect() {
        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
//            TwitterAuthActivity.start(activity, requestToken.getAuthenticationURL(), AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            LogUtils.info(TAG + "  " + e.getErrorMessage());
            LogUtils.info(TAG + "  " + e.getExceptionCode());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == AUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
            String url = TwitterAuthActivity.getResultUrl(data);
            if (url != null && url.startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                try {
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                    PreferencesManager.setTwitterToken(activity, accessToken.getToken());
                    PreferencesManager.setTwitterSecret(activity, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while parsing tokens", e);
                    listener.onExceptionOccured(e);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle 
`implementation group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.6'` for

**It's working fine before, but suddenly it showing Error message like below.** ,  for like `requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);` I have seen many posts for the same error message, a major user suggested below solution any of the not working for me.

**1)** Update twitter4j from 4.0.3 to latest 4.0.6= not working for me

**2)** Add Callback URL = I have already added callback URL.

> 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An
>   accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when
>   requests are being denied due to update limits
>   (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
>           Callback URL not approved for this client application.
>   Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application
>   settings
>           Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
>             http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8e063946 or
>             http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=fe607b42
>           TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8e063946-fe607b42], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1,
>   rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.6}
>               at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
>               at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
>               at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
>               at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:115)
>               at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:92)
>               at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:296)
>               at android_support.ane.b(TwitterSocialHelper.java:69)
>               at android_support.ane.a(TwitterSocialHelper.java:102)

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error message, and link in it, point to this being the server rate limiting your queries. Have you posted more then 2400 posts using this API key today? Or exceeded any of the other limits listed in the first link?

Comment: Or, have you changed the callback URL? This is a pretty clear message: `Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings`

Comment: @MattClark I have not exceeded any post limit. Second I have added callback URL for android `twittersdk://` for IOS `twitterkit-mykey://` it's working for IOS there is issue with Android only

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?